# How can i implement parallel process in perl?

Tags: perl

```
I have written a perl script which does the following things sequentially,
1.Copying .gcda files from other 50 remote machines to my home dir.
2.It generates GCOV
3.Merge the GCOV files

  As i mentioned above it is working sequentially and it takes more than an hour to complete the task.But i want to execute these steps in parallel.
```

For Ex: I am copying from remote machine1 to DIR1  .....from machine50 to DIR50
 So totally i am copying from 50 machines to 50 directories respectively.
then it generates gcov for all 50 directories.

My current requirement is as soon as i copy from machine 1 i should start generation of gcov in parallel,after gcov generated for 2 directories i need to start merging.

but, i am not suppose to use Parallel::ForkManager module and i cannot use threads also.

Please give some idea how can i implement...

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Is this homework? If not, why can't you use threads or that module?

Comment: I would like to help you, but I am not allowed to help people who cannot use threads or Parallel::ForkManager.

Comment: I am able to implement with Parallel::ForkManager but i am not suppose to use that..

Comment: And why are you not supposed to use it?

Comment: If you don't tell us what about Parallel::ForkManager and threads you can't use, we'd be wasting out time trying to come up with alternatives.

Comment: I should not use in my assignment so,

Answer (score 2):

Your question appears to be

> For academic purposes, I'd like to learn how to use `fork`. How do I do this?

Modules like Parallel::ForkManager were written so you don't have to use `fork` directly because it can be tricky. If you want to know how to use `fork`, you should therefore study [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel%3a%3aForkManager). It's too big to copy here.

Keep in mind that `fork`, `wait` and `waitpid` translate quite thinly to the system calls with the same name, so you should be familiar with `man 2 fork`, `man 2 wait` and `man 2 waitpid`.

[perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) might also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use threads and you can't use a forking module, then the only reasonable solution is that you're intended to use `fork()` manually to split your process into multiple processes. Unfortunately, managing the child processes thus produced can be quite tricky, which is why modules like `Parallel::ForkManager` were written - but it's valuable to know what's going on if you're interested in UNIX programming.

I'm assuming the restrictions are because this is homework or some other academic exercise, so the restrictions fit if they really want you to learn about forking.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how can i implement with fork().

Comment: your assumptions are correct it is for academic exercise and i am new to perl :)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't, because it's a big topic and I don't have time. However, there's a lot of information online about it because fork is a standard UNIX system call and has been used by many, many people. Perl's implementation has a few quirks of its own, but it behaves almost exactly the same as the `fork` call in the standard POSIX C library. So you can read most documentation about `fork` and come away wiser for it. Short version: fork child processes to do the work, wait for them to complete, then do the next step from the parent.